# Undefined is not an object in state array, trying to find state array length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

So I have a state array of some values, and it says that undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state.unavailable). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
 firebase.database().ref('recipes').orderByChild('custard'). equalTo(0).once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var variable = snapshot.val();
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < this.state.unavailable.length; i++){
    if (variable.unavailable[i] == 0) {
        console.log(variable);
    }
  }
});
```

where it's all initiated

```
constructor() {
super()
this.state = {
  refreshing: false,
  checked: false,
  one: false,
  two: false,
  three: false,
  four: false,
  five: false,
  six: false,
  seven: false,
  eight: false,
  nine: false,
  key: 1,
  list: [],
  unavailable: []
 }
}
```

Comment: Where is your state initialiased and where is unavailable being initalised also?

Comment: ive added it to the bottom now

Comment: the original code was initialized in componentdidmount

Comment: Is `this.state.unavailable` asynchronous? We might need more context to help

Comment: no it isn't, but don't worry it's been solved now. Thanks for all the help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrow function to overcome the current context this problem.

like below..

```
firebase.database().ref('recipes').orderByChild('custard'). equalTo(0).once('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    var variable = snapshot.val();
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.state.unavailable.length; i++){
      if (variable.unavailable[i] == 0) {
          console.log(variable);
      }
    }
  });
```

Or take a variable on up side this code block like below..

```
 var self= this;

 firebase.database().ref('recipes').orderByChild('custard'). equalTo(0).once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var variable = snapshot.val();
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < self.state.unavailable.length; i++){
    if (variable.unavailable[i] == 0) {
        console.log(variable);
    }
  }
});
```